# If someone forgot to read Surah Al-Kahf on Friday, can they read it on Saturday?

Tags: surat-al-kahf

If someone made the intention to read Surah Al-Kahf on Friday, but he got busy and he forgot to read it. Can he read it on Saturday?

Comment: I think we might need some context: reading a particular surah on a particular day is never mandatory. In addition: you can read any surah on any day. Could you please add some details ?

Comment: There are great rewards on reading Surah Al-Kahf on Friday, and it isn't mandatory. The only mandatory surah is Surah Al-Fatiha in salah. I wanted to know if someone will receive the rewards of reading it if he forgot to read it.